# Friendly artillery fire from the Boomers

Tags: pc, fallout-new-vegas

I managed to avoid the Boomer artillery fire and speak with their leader. They promised not to fire on me any more, and I already performed a quest for them and have a reputation of "accepted" with the Boomers.

They still fire on me if I come near the Nellis gate or the area in front of it. They don't mind killing their own people in the process.

I don't want to reload and redo the quest for them again, is there any way of circumventing that bug, e.g. via some console commands?

Comment: Odd, that bug is [listed](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Nellis_Air_Force_Base#Bugs) as XBox/PS3 only. You might want to head over to the Wiki and update it to confirm on PC. Since it's not listed there for PC, at this stage it's unknown if a console command might fix it. :(

Comment: As Far as i know, the Boomers "always" shoot on everything living that comes near them! The only Exception is when you wear a boomer-outfit, then they won't harm you.. correct me if iam wrong.

Answer (score 3):

the console command is SetReputation #
the ID for the boomers is FFAE8
and you are going to want to use 1 for the # so the exact command is

Set Reputation FFAE8 1

this should reset your reputation to liked with them and not your quests

Answer (score 0):

Fast-travel from the world map should put you somewhere inside the compound, right? Or is that location too close to the gate?